# Scrapy TCP Connection Timed Out

Tags: python, tcp, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy for the first time. (Yes i seen the other post on this and got no answer out of it). So i was wondering to make it super simple to have it run atleast.

Here is my spider code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class Spider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domain = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/sfc/npo/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//p")
        for titles in titles:
            title = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            link = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            print title, link
```

and i get this error 
"TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time..."

I tried this with another website URL and still nothing.

If it is the porting that might be blocked what ports should i open (but at the same time not letting my computer vulnerable)
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a proxy. If yes either set the http_proxy environment variable or use proxy middle ware of the scrapy.